# How can i define databound in KendoUI Grid , syntax is very confusing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kedno-Grid , with details below:

This is the data source:

```
    var data = $scope.salesgroups;
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        //data: data,
        transport: {
            read: function (e) {
                e.success(data);
            },
            update: function (e) {
                e.success();
            },
            create: function (e) {
                var item = e.data;
                item.Id = data.length + 1;
                e.success(item);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Name: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    });

Var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        scrollable: false,
        navigatable: true,
        editable: {
            createAt: "bottom"
        },            
        toolbar: ["save", "cancel", "create"],
        columns: ["Name"]
    }).data("kendoGrid")
```

The below code is for adding a new row when the user clicks on tab on the last row of the grid.

```
    grid.tbody.on('keydown', function (e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 9)
        {
           if ($(e.target).closest('td').is(':last-child') && $(e.target).closest('tr').is(':last- 
                    child')) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    grid.addRow();
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

Now where do I define the "databound" ? I want to add the following below code which will replace the buttons with font awesome icons instead of create  and delete buttons

```
     dataBound: function (e) {            
     e.sender.tbody.find(".k-grid-edit").each(function (idx, element) {
    if (!$scope.validateDisabled)
      $(element).remove();
        else {
        $(element).removeClass("k-button");
          $(element).removeClass("k-button-icontext");
       }
    });

      e.sender.tbody.find(".k-grid-Delete").each(function (idx, element) {
      if (!$scope.validateDisabled)
        $(element).remove();
       else {
          $(element).removeClass("k-button");
         $(element).removeClass("k-button-icontext");
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`dataBound`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound) is a root property of grid parameters:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ...,
    scrollable: ...,
    navigatable: ...,
    editable: ...,            
    toolbar: ...,
    columns: ...,
    dataBound: function() {

    }
}).data("kendoGrid")
```